# Add Case Switch To PHP Array()

Tags: php

### PHP SCRIPT:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$Y = 2017;
$UK_Holidays = array(
    'New Year\'s Day'   => array(
        'start'         => strtotime('30-12-'.$Y.' 00:00:00'),
        'end'           => strtotime('30-12-'.$Y.' 23:59:59'),
        'type'          => 'Bank holiday',
        'Observed'      => 'Default'
    ),
    '2nd January (substitute day)' => array(
        'start'         => '',
        'end'           => '',
        'type'          => 'Local holiday',
        'Observed'      => 'Scotland'
    ),
);
echo json_encode($UK_Holidays, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

### OUTPUT:

```
{
    "New Year's Day": {
        "start": 1514592000,
        "end": 1514678399,
        "type": "Bank holiday",
        "Observed": "Default"
    },
    "2nd January (substitute day)": {
        "start": "",
        "end": "",
        "type": "Local holiday",
        "Observed": "Scotland"
    }
}
```

---

### MORE INFORMATION:

I have a lot more holidays to implement into this PHP script, some of which are dependant on the day another holiday lands on. For 2nd January (substitute day), I've developed a switch case;

**PHP Case Switch For 2nd January (substitute day):**

```
function calculateBankHolidays($Y) {

    $bankHols = Array();

    switch (date("w", strtotime("01-01-$Y 00:00:00"))) {
        case 6:
            $bankHols[] = "03-01-$Y";
            break;
        case 0:
            $bankHols[] = "02-01-$Y";
            break;
        default:
            $bankHols[] = "01-01-$Y";
    }
    return $bankHols;

}
```

**Outputs:**

```
[
    {
        "New Year's": {
            "Start Date": "02-01-2017"
        }
    }
]
```

### QUESTION:

What is the *best* way to implement my case switch into my PHP Script?

Comment: Regarding your high-level goal, I tried this once.  Got the easy ones done, like 2nd Monday in October.  But when it came to doing Easter / Good Friday there's just no reasonable way to do that one.  I ended up just hard-coding the holidays for the next 10 years.  An hour or two of clerical work and I was done, moved on.

Comment: Just remembered, check out this too:  http://holidaywebservice.com/

Comment: Well Easter should be straight forward with [easter_date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.easter-date.php) and Good Friday will just be the friday before easter.

Comment: Jeez, PHP has everything.  I had no idea it had easter_date() function.  I never imagined it would be worth looking for.  Thanks for that.  I guess I could have implemented it after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` is your friend here, combined with the relative formats (see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).  You can do things like.

```
$year = date('Y');
$ts_Jan1 = strtotime("Jan 1 $year -1 day next weekday");
$ts_Jan2 = strtotime("next weekday", $ts_Jan1);
$ts2 = strtotime("first Monday Jan $year");
```

EDIT:  Added this [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pt1f-9q54) to show working code.  The dates generated by this working code match the dates in the table at the link provided by OP: https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/uk/2nd-january

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as such. It needs to check whether the day after New Year's Day is a Friday to exist in the first place. Ideally I need to have an IF statemetn prior `'2nd January (substitute day)' => array(`

Comment: I found this definition: "If either or both of January 1 and 2 fall on a Saturday or Sunday, the bank holidays are moved to the next week days. For instance, if January 1 falls on a Saturday and January 2 on a Sunday, the bank holidays are moved to January 3 and 4.".  The code above will do that for you.  `$ts_Jan1` is the day the Jan 1 holiday is observed, which may not be Jan 1.  Same for `$ts_Jan2`.

Comment: Ah, I think I just got it.  Jan 2 is observed as a holiday if and only if it Jan 2 is a Friday--and a working day in all other cases.  Man, weird way to allocate holidays.

Comment: Agreed, there are more weirder ones to come! I need to figure out how to create IF statements within or so I set loads of variables?... My source is: [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/) > [2nd January in United Kingdom](https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/uk/2nd-january)

Comment: lol, that was the source for my cut&pasted definiion above.  So, looks like "Jan 2" is always a holiday even if it is not obsevered on the 2nd day of Jan.  In fact, it is observed on the weekday after the day Jan 1 is observed.  This is exactly what the code above does: `strtotime("next weekday", $ts_Jan1);`

Comment: `strtotime("next weekday", '30-12-'.$Y)` outputs `86400` is this the time till the next day?

Comment: I added a link above to working code in a PHPfiddle.  `strtotime` returns a unix timestamp (number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970).  This can be formatted however you want with `date` (as is done in the PHPfiddle).

Comment: Just got it working using `(strtotime('01-01-'.$Y.' 00:00:00') + strtotime("next weekday", '01-01-'.$Y.' 00:00:00'))` will check your link out now.

Comment: Don't know why that is working.  For its 2nd arg, `strtotime` takes a unix timestamp which is a large-ish integer.  You pass in a string.  It may be some fluke that the string is coerced to something that at least in this case gives you what looks like a correct answer.

Comment: Just tested, doesn't work for 2021 when New Year's Day is on a Friday

Comment: I just ran the PHPfiddle with more years and got `For 2021, holidays are Fri, Jan 1 and Mon, Jan 4`.  Isn't that correct?  Jan 1 is observed on Fri, Jan 1 and Jan 2 is observed on Mon, Jan 4 (the next weekday).

Comment: Shouldn't all the New Year's Day dates be on the 1st?

Comment: Nope. As in your link "the bank holidays are moved to the next week days".  So if Jan 1 is a Sunday, it is observed on Mon, Jan 2 (in which case Jan 2 will be observed on Tue, Jan 3).  By "observed", I mean that is the day you do not have to go into work.

Comment: Yes, New Year's Day is alway on the 1st Jan, this additional one though depends on what day New Year's Day falls on. Just got this working with: **Start:** `strtotime('01-01-'.$Y.' +1 Weekday 00:00:00')`, **End:** `strtotime('01-01-'.$Y.' +1 Weekday 23:59:59')` Your answer is still very useful so I'm going to award it